# How to push from view controller to navigation view controller using prepareForSegue method?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue, ios5.1

I have a project which has a view controller as initial screen and then a view controller embedded inside a navigational view controller. I also have a button on first screen on click of which I want the navigational controller screen to be opened.

I clicked on button and then on ' connections inspector', I added push event to that navigational controller, but segue is not happening. How could I achieve it please?

## SOLUTION

Finally after a bit of research I managed to get this thing working. Here is the code i am using:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Source Controller = %@", [segue sourceViewController]);
    NSLog(@"Destination Controller = %@", [segue destinationViewController]);
    NSLog(@"Segue Identifier = %@", [segue identifier]);
    
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mysegue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"coming here");
        
     SecondViewController *loginViewController = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        
       //SecondViewController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
        
        [self presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the Navigation Controller's connection to the embedded view controller is set up correctly? The first view controller should be connected to the Navigation Controller, with a `Push` style segue, and the navigation controller should be connected to the second view controller, with a `Relationship` style segue.

At any rate, one of the official Apple tutorials does just this, so you might be able to compare your code to it and see if there's a difference: [Your Second iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CreatingAddView/CreatingAddView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH6-SW1). The `prepareForSegue` method itself isn't really involved with firing the segue; it is just invoked before the segue runs to prepare the new view controller.

Comment: Hi Paul, Yes, they are all correctly set. I have found the solution and edited my answer as well. Thanks a lot for suggestions.